# Trying to insert node at 3rd position in linkedlist java

Tags: java, linked-list

So like the title says I'm trying to input a node in the third position of the linked list. The way I originally tried to do it was to insert two places down the list after numberOfItems was >= 3. I figured if I was getting an error it would be outputting the last 2 Players wrongly but it's just continuing to output Player 1. Can anybody point me to the right direction as to why this is happening?

Here is my linkedlist class

```
public class PlayerLinkedList extends ShellLinkedList
{
public PlayerLinkedList()
{
  super();
}//end PlayerLinkedList constructor
public void insert(Player p)
{
  if(numberOfItems >= 3)
  {
     PlayerNode pn = new PlayerNode(p);
     head = pn;
     pn.setNext(head.getNext().getNext());
     numberOfItems++;
  }  
  else 
  {
     PlayerNode pn = new PlayerNode(p);
     if(head == null)
     {
        head = pn;
     }
     pn.setNext(head);
     head = pn;
     numberOfItems++;
  }     
}//end insert method
public Player delete(int searchID) throws DataStructureException
{
   PlayerNode current = head;
   PlayerNode previous = null;
   while(current != null && current.getPlayer().getID()!=searchID)
   {
     previous = current;
     current = current.getNext();
   }//end while
   if(current == null) //not found
     throw new DataStructureException(searchID + "not found: cannot be deleted");
     else
     {
     if(current == head)
        head = head.getNext(); //delete head
        else            
           previous.setNext(current.getNext());
           numberOfItems--;
           return current.getPlayer();        
     }//end else 
}//end delete
}//end class
```

Also just for reference here is my ShellLinkedList class

```
public abstract class ShellLinkedList
{
   protected PlayerNode head;
   protected int numberOfItems;

   public ShellLinkedList()
   {
      head = null;
      numberOfItems = 0;
   }//end ShellLinkedList constructor

   public int getNumberOfItems()
   {
      return numberOfItems;
   }// end of getnumberOfItems

   public boolean isEmpty()
   {
      return (numberOfItems==0);
   }//end isEmpty

   public String toString()
   {
      String listString="";
      PlayerNode current = head;
      for(int i = 0; i<numberOfItems && current != null; i++)
      {
         listString += current.getPlayer().toString()+"\n";
         current = current.getNext();
      }
      return listString;
   }//end toString
}//end class
```

My input is:

```
Player one = new Player(1, "Mike", "Mario");
Player two = new Player(2, "Brian", "Halo");
Player three = new Player(3, "John", "Minecraft");
Player four = new Player(4, "Thrall", "WoW");
Player five = new Player(5, "Scott", "Metroid");
list.insert(one);
list.insert(two);
list.insert(three);
list.insert(four);
list.insert(five);
System.out.println(list.toString());
```

And my output is:

```
id: 3   name: John  game: Minecraft
id: 2   name: Brian game: Halo
id: 1   name: Mike  game: Mario
id: 1   name: Mike  game: Mario
id: 1   name: Mike  game: Mario
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code, your insert method behaves differently when `numberOfItems >= 3` which is why you are not able to add more than 3 times.  In that code block you are creating a new `PlayerNode` instance but you do not keep any reference to it.

You should also check whether you are expecting normal [`List#add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-) behaviour which appends to the end of a list not the beginning.

Comment: What I was originally trying to do was use the

 pn.setNext(head.getNext().getNext());

line to set the head as a marker and insert 2 spots down from that. Would that even work or was my logic faulty?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding

```
head.getNext().setNext(pn);
```

after

```
pn.setNext(head.getNext().getNext());
```

Comment: I think your code may still have bugs, I would suggest you get a pen and paper and draw out how your objects are connected after inserting 2-3 values.  You can use the debugger in your IDE to verify what you want is what you have...